# Need to pass filter with URL

Tags: filter, filtering

Hey can someone please help this is driving me nuts. I need to make a url from the 3 filters 'ecvnd', 'ecdiv', and 'ecclas' and I have values for all 3 plus the base url. I'm stuck and I think this wouldn't be that difficult if my colleague didn't leave me guessing. This is for ecom site so I need the filters to display the proper products in the link.

the values are as such: ECVND=59375, ECDIV=53 and ECCLAS=59

the closest I got was, but not returning the right products.
https://shop.michells.com/orders/catalog/filter_ECVND=59375&filter_ECDIV=53&ECCLAS=59

As you can see from the snippet below, the filters are hidden in the url on click but when you arrive I need the proper filters to display as there are thousands of other products in the system.

[ss snippet hint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRgen.gif)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0050)http://getbootstrap.com/examples/starter-template/ -->
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">

        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">

        <title>Henry F. Michell's</title>


        <link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="/css/michells.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="/js/respond.js"></script>
            <script src="/js/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

        <!--[if lt IE 10]>
            <link href="/css/michells.ie.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <![endif]-->

        <!--[if !IE]>
            <link href="/css/michells.notie.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <![endif]-->



        <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
        <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bree+Serif" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="/css/font-awesome.min.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="/css/grid.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="/css/select2.css" media="(min-width: 768px)" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="/css/select2-bootstrap.css" media="(min-width: 768px)" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="/img/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon">      

    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="subpage hidden-print">
            <img src="/img/bg-subpage-banner.jpg">
        </div>

        <div class="container-fluid">

            <!-- HEADER -->
            <div class="header">
                <!-- green bar across the top -->
                <div class="row hidden-print">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-11 lg-right navigationBar">

                        <!-- contents of the green nav bar -->                      

                                                    <!-- expanded links -->
                        <ul class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">
                            <li><a href="http://www.michells.com/">Michells.com</a>|</li>
                            <li><a href="http://www.michells.com/contactus">Contact Us</a>|</li>
                            <li class="hoverMenu"><a href="#">My Account</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu myaccountMenu left" role="menu">
                                    <li><a href="/orders/account/changepassword">Change Password</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/orders/account/orderhistory">Order History</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/orders/account/statements">Customer Statements</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/orders/plantreport/plantreport">Plant Report</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            |</li>
                            <li><a href="/orders/cart/savedcarts">Saved Carts</a>|</li>
                            <li><a href="/orders/account">Account 1</a> <a class="small" href="/orders/login/logout">Logout</a></li>
                        </ul>


                             <!-- mobile menu -->
                        <div class="hidden-md hidden-lg right">
                            <div class="btn-group">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                                </button>

                                <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" role="menu">
                                    <li><a href="http://www.michells.com/">Michells.com</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="http://www.michells.com/contactus">Contact Us</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/orders/account/changepassword">Change Password</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/orders/account/orderhistory">Order History</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/orders/account/statements">Customer Statements</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/orders/cart/savedcarts">Saved Carts</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/orders/plantreport/plantreport">Plant Report</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>  
                            <!--/mobile menu -->
                                                    <!-- /nav bar contents -->
                    </div>
                </div><!-- /green nav bar -->

                <img class="logo" src="/img/michells-logo.png">

                                    <div class="mobilelogoutIcon visible-xs hidden-print"><a class="small" href="/orders/login/logout"><i class='fa fa-sign-out'></i></div>
                    <div class="tabletWelcome hidden-xs hidden-print">
                        <div>1 <a class="small" href="/orders/login/logout">Logout</a></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="minicart hidden-print">
                        <a href="/orders/cart/reviewcart">
                        <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
                        <span class="shoppingCartQty">0</span>
                        <span class="items"> Items</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>



            </div> 
            <!-- / HEADER -->





        <!-- Vendors -->
        <div class="contents vendorselect">
            <h1><span class="hidden-xs"> Online Ordering: </span>Vendors</h1>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 loginform">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
                                <form id="run" action="/orders/catalog/filter" method="post">
                                    <p>Please select a vendor to view their products</p>
                                    <select name="filter_ECVND" id="filter_ECVND" class="form-control">
                                        <option>Select Vendor</option>
                                        <option value='940' >Agri Starts (940)</option><option value='1004' >Aldershot (1004)</option><option value='72761' >Aris (72761)</option><option value='26600' >Aris Horticulture Inc (26600)</option><option value='3650' >Athena Brazil (3650)</option><option value='6795' >Blue Heron (6795)</option><option value='9735' >Botany (9735)</option><option value='07600' >Bountiful Farm (07600)</option><option value='9225' >Burchell Nursery (9225)</option><option value='10500' >Cal Seedling (10500)</option><option value='11740' >Casa Flora (11740)</option><option value='921' >Cohen Nurseries (921)</option><option value='14085' >Colony (14085)</option><option value='13688' >CLI (13688)</option><option value='18997' >Dummen (18997)</option><option value='18997' >Dummen Group (18997)</option><option value='18997' >Dummen USA (18997)</option><option value='22470' >Dummen/Fides (22470)</option><option value='19300' >Duwaynes (19300)</option><option value='47200' >Ecke (47200)</option><option value='47200' >Ecke Geraniums, LLC (47200)</option><option value='20100' >Eckert&#039;s Greenhouse (20100)</option><option value='20415' >Ekstrom (20415)</option><option value='20710' >Emerald Coast Growers (20710)</option><option value='21320' >Euro American (21320)</option><option value='14085' >F Henny (14085)</option><option value='21901' >Fairy Gardening (21901)</option><option value='22844' >Floral Plant Growers (22844)</option><option value='23720' >Four Star (23720)</option><option value='22702' >Geraniums (22702)</option><option value='26572' >Green Fuse (26572)</option><option value='26473' >Greenheart (26473)</option><option value='26760' >Gro &#039;N Sell (26760)</option><option value='26750' >Gro Link (26750)</option><option value='26920' >Gulley (26920)</option><option value='26920' >Gulley Greenhouse (26920)</option><option value='35290' >Knox Nursery (35290)</option><option value='35499' >Koba (35499)</option><option value='35500' >Kogut (35500)</option><option value='35700' >Kube Pak (35700)</option><option value='36091' >Lancaster Farms (36091)</option><option value='38030' >Lucas Greenhouses (38030)</option><option value='28480' >Marjama (28480)</option><option value='39345' >Mast Young Plants (39345)</option><option value='40185' >Meadowview (40185)</option><option value='43322' >Morris (43322)</option><option value='43370' >Mountain Creek (43370)</option><option value='46928' >Obersinner (46928)</option><option value='49150' >Pell Greenhouse (49150)</option><option value='51480' >Plainview Growers (51480)</option><option value='51480' >Plainview Growers Inc (51480)</option><option value='51500' >Pleasant View (51500)</option><option value='51555' >Plug Connection (51555)</option><option value='53625' >Reardon (53625)</option><option value='56105' >Russell (56105)</option><option value='57600' >Scott Farms (57600)</option><option value='59375' selected>Silverleaf Greenhouses (59375)</option><option value='59680' >Skagit Gardens (59680)</option><option value='61100' >Spada Nursery (61100)</option><option value='61166' >Speedling Blairsville (61166)</option><option value='61160' >Speedling Inc (61160)</option><option value='61160' >Speedling Inc. (61160)</option><option value='62850' >Sun Gro (62850)</option><option value='32690' >Sunfire (32690)</option><option value='63290' >Swift Greenhouse (63290)</option><option value='22701' >Syngenta (22701)</option><option value='22701' >Syngenta Flowers (22701)</option><option value='22700' >Syngenta Flowers, Inc (22700)</option><option value='51555' >The Plug Connection (51555)</option><option value='66546' >Twin Srpings (66546)</option><option value='68065' >Van Essen (68065)</option><option value='69605' >Wagner Greenhouses Inc (69605)</option><option value='69899' >Walters Gardens (69899)</option><option value='70250' >Welby (70250)</option><option value='72050' >Woodburn Nursery (72050)</option><option value='72055' >Woodburn Nursery (72055)</option>                                    </select>
                                    <div class="btncontainer right">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default right">Select</button>
                                    </div>

                                </form>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <!-- / Vendors -->      
        </div><!-- /.container -->




        <div class="footerouter hidden-print">  
            <div class="footerinner">
                <footer class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-4 row center">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 row">
                            <img src="/img/michells-logo.png" class="footerlogo">
                            <p class="stayconnected"><em>Stay Connected</em></p>
                            <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/hfmichells" target="_blank"><img src="/img/icon-fb.png"></a></div>
                            <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="https://twitter.com/Michells1890" target="_blank"><img src="/img/icon-tw.png"></a></div>
                            <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="http://www.linkedin.com/company/henry-f-michell-company" target="_blank"><img src="/img/icon-in.png"></a></div>
                            <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="https://plus.google.com/101209637864605782915/posts" target="_blank"><img src="/img/icon-gp.png"></a></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-8">
                        <div class="col-xs-7 col-md-3">
                            <ul>
                                <li><strong>Main</strong></li>
                                <li><a href="http://www.michells.com/">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://www.michells.com/company">About Us</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://www.michells.com/sales">Sales &amp; Service</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://www.michells.com/brochure">Michell's Product Catalog</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://www.michells.com/availability">Availability</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://www.michells.com/contactus">Contact Us</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-xs-5 col-md-3">
                            <ul>
                                <li><strong>Products</strong></li>
                                <li><a href="http://www.michells.com/seed">Seeds</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://www.michells.com/nursery">Nursery</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://www.michells.com/plugs">Plugs</a> </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-xs-7 col-md-3">
                            <ul>
                                <li><strong>Exclusive Partners</strong></li>
                                <li><a href="http://www.michells.com/green-fuse-botanicals">Green Fuse</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://www.michells.com/cli">CLI</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://www.michells.com/fairy">Fairy Flowers</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-5 col-md-3">
                            <ul>
                                <li><strong>Online Ordering</strong></li>
                                <li><a href="/orders/catalog">Shop Now</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/orders/login">Login</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://www.michells.com/register">Register</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 footerDisc">Pricing subject to change depending upon volume</div>
                </footer>

                <div class="pagebottom">
                    <span class="getupdates"><em>Get Updates!</em></span>
                    <a target="_blank" class="signup" href="http://visitor.r20.constantcontact.com/d.jsp?llr=gpmby6oab&amp;p=oi&amp;m=1115542303206&amp;sit=6diisxiib&amp;f=2dbee31f-253a-4d91-a0f8-4a2206e36974">Sign Up for Email Updates</a><span class="small">Michell's <span class="Labels">2017</span>. All rights Reserved. <span class="bar">|</span> <a href="http://www.michells.com/sitemap" class="white">Sitemap</a><span class="bar">|</span><a href="http://www.michells.com/terms" class="white">Terms &amp; Conditions</a><span class="bar">|</span><a href="http://www.michells.com/privacy" class="white">Privacy Policy</a></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="device-xs visible-xs hidden-print"></div>
        <div class="device-sm visible-sm hidden-print"></div>
        <div class="device-md visible-md hidden-print"></div>
        <div class="device-lg visible-lg hidden-print"></div>
        <div class="device-landscape visible-landscape hidden-print"></div>
        <div class="device-portrait visible-portrait hidden-print"></div>




        <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
        ================================================== -->

        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/select2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/hfm.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/hfm.vendors.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<!--
    hfm.vendors.init();
    //-->
</script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery('.hoverMenu').hover(
        function() {
        jQuery(this).addClass('open');
        }, function() {
        jQuery(this).removeClass('open');
        }
        );


        </script>






    </body>
</html>
```

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Please include any JavaScripts or details on the framework you are using.  Since the form is `method="post"` it would not "naturally" construct a URL like that without JS, only `GET` requests do that "out of the box".

Comment: updated full page source code

Comment: base link:
https://shop.michells.com/orders/catalog/

Comment: Please review the [Question Guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for constructing a better question, so that we can help you better; simply posting your entire page's source code does not help to isolate the issue.

Comment: framework was requested in comments... I had a snippet before....

Comment: we're writing an external script to write existing filters into the url... thank you, mods can close this question